# problem with downloading apps

Tags: email

I am using Microsoft Lumia 535. I have  problem with downloading apps in my phone. When I download it is showing to save my Microsoft account password. But I am not able to save my account password . I came to know that if I sync my Microsoft account I can solve the problem of downloading. But even I am not able to do that . Please do help me with a solution.

Answer (score 1):

This things mostly happen when you recently changed the password of Microsoft account. So they are just cross checking is that it's you before downloading or making purchase of any app. 
So whenever they ask you for the password, just put it correct and save it. 
I will suggest you to use WiFi connection for this kind of things.